# publisher and rosinit

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a small coding problem while writing publisher. Usually I write publisher inside main function in my code:

```
pub.publish(data);
```

after initialize ros, create nodhandle, and define publisher. Similar like this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)).

Now, I trying to publish not in my main function. But this could not work since the ros initialization and nodeHandle etc are in main function. And if I write the nodehandle in my one of my subfunction, the nodehandle will also directly off after the subfunction being called.

I was thinking if the rosinit could be initialized before the main function, but still have found the way.

Let me now if someone have suggestion. Thx

Cheers,
Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11351/publisher-and-rosinit/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want the publisher to be declared as a global object. You create the node handle in your start up routine/constructor and initialise the publisher from that.

```
 //globally defined
 ros::Publisher pub_;
  
 //in your constructor
 int main(int argc, char** argv){
 ...
 pub_ = nh_.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);
 ...
 }
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make the node handle a global or class variable so you can reference it from anywhere. You can declare the node handle, without initializing it, then do the initialization in your main function.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-09-28**:
creating nodeHandle before ros initialization is not allowed. But, I made it work by defining variable in a class.

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-09-28**:
the nodeHandle can be set globlally? I think I have tried that one, but I'll check again soon.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't like global variables, you can also pass the publisher by reference to a function:

```
void worker (ros::Publisher& pub)
{
  //...
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  //...
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud>("points2", 1);
  //...
  worker(pub);
  //...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5